# Postgresql : Find the string with the closest substring match

Tags: string, postgresql, pattern-matching

If I have a table test with values like :

```
id | value
----------------
1  | ABC 1-2-3
2  | AB 1-2-3-4-5
3  | ABC 1
4  | ABC 1-2
5  | ABC
```

and the input string I'm trying to is **ABC 1-2-3-4-5**, then the closest substring match (if I could call it that) should be **ABC 1-2-3**. Row # 2 should not match because it doesn't have the "ABC". I've only been able to search for the string if the input string is shorter than the actual records, but not if it's longer. e.g

```
select * from test where value ilike 'ABC 1-2%';
```

but this also does not give me an exact record, but only those starting with ABC 1-2. How do I construct the proper sql statement to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reverse the comparison:

```
select * from test
where 'ABC 1-2-3-4-5' ilike value || '%'
order by length(value) desc
```

The best (ie longest) matches will be returned first.

Comment: It works like magic. How? Will it work similarly on MySQL/Oracle/MSSQL as well?

Comment: @Vikas the "magic" is reversing the usual condition of `where my_column like some_value` to `where some_value like my_column%`, which in words means "where some_value starts with my_column". Yes, this will work for all databases (but change `ilike` to `like` - `ilike` is Postgres only).

Comment: Have you written more on this topic? I would like learn more to create a solution that can stand the test of time. (various combinations of conditions including multiple ILIKE conditions)

Comment: @Vikas no, this is all I have written about it

Answer (score 7):

You may be interested in [pg_trgm extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/pgtrgm.html):

```
create extension if not exists pg_trgm;
```

Standard similarities for your data are as follows:

```
select *, similarity(value, 'ABC 1-2-3-4-5')
from test
order by 3 desc;

 id |    value     | similarity 
----+--------------+------------
  2 | AB 1-2-3-4-5 |        0.8
  1 | ABC 1-2-3    |   0.714286
  4 | ABC 1-2      |   0.571429
  3 | ABC 1        |   0.428571
  5 | ABC          |   0.285714
(5 rows)
```

However you can always add additional criteria in `WHERE` clause:

```
select *, similarity(value, 'ABC 1-2-3-4-5')
from test
where value ilike 'abc%'
order by 3 desc;

 id |   value   | similarity 
----+-----------+------------
  1 | ABC 1-2-3 |   0.714286
  4 | ABC 1-2   |   0.571429
  3 | ABC 1     |   0.428571
  5 | ABC       |   0.285714
(4 rows)
```

Comment: I upvoted this because there's an actual measure of similarity and i can probably use this in the future.